# select scatter plot dot on external click event google charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have an external ul li list containing john and smith this list is not part of scatter chart **(html code not define here)**. When user click on john or smith, scatter plot's related dot should be selected and change its color from blue to red.

Secondly I use google.visualization.events.addListener(scatterChart, 'select', tableSelectHandler); to change dot color but its color didn't remain changed. Is there any solution for these two situations. I use following code.

```
var jsonData = '[[{"type":"number","label":"row"},{"type":"string","label":"Screen Name"},{"type":"number","label": "Followers Count"},{"type":"number","label":"Following Count"},{"type":"datetime","label":"Date"}],[1,"john",215,263,"Date(2016,1,10,17,07,38)"],[1,"smith",315,363,"Date(2016,1,10,18,07,38)"]]'; 

   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData));


  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'width': "100%",
      'filterColumnLabel': 'row',
      'minValue': 1,
      'maxValue': totalTweets
    },
      // Explicitly positions the thumbs at position 3 and 8,
    // out of the possible range of 1 to 10.
    'state': {'lowValue': 1, 'highValue': 1000}
  });

   // Create a scatter chart, passing some options
  var scatterChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
    'containerId': 'scatter_chart_div',
    'options': {
      'width': "100%",
      'height': 390,
      'legend': 'none',
      explorer : {
            actions : [ 'dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset' ],
        },
    },

    // The scatter chart will use the following columns
    // out of all the available ones.
    'view': {'columns': [4, 2]}

  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(scatterChart, 'select', tableSelectHandler);

  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, scatterChart);

    function tableSelectHandler() {

        var selection = scatterChart.getChart().getSelection();
        if(selection.length) {
            var selectedScreenName = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 1);

            // Select sidebar screen_name
            $("#" + selectedScreenName).trigger("click");

$("#scatter_chart_div div div div svg g g g circle[stroke-width='0']").attr("fill", "#fff000");


            // scroll to view sidebar screen_name
            var position = $("#" + selectedScreenName).offset().top - 
            $('#singleUserTimelineScreenNamesContainer').offset().top + 
            $('#singleUserTimelineScreenNamesContainer').scrollTop();
            $('#singleUserTimelineScreenNamesContainer').animate({ scrollTop: position });


            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

            view.setColumns([1,2, {
                type: 'string',
                role: 'style',
                calc: function (dt, i) {
                console.log(i);
                    return (i == row) ? 'color: red' : null;
                }
            }]);

            scatterChart.draw(view);

        }
    }

    // Draw the dashboard.
    dashboard.draw(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change point color is a style column. Looks like you were on that path.

Added a style column to `jsonData` and set the initial style to `null`
Added new column index to `scatterChart` `view` option

To change color, see...
`tableSelectHandler` and `$('.name-container').click` for clicking `li`

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['controls'], 'callback': drawChart});

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = '[[{"type":"number","label":"row"},{"type":"string","label":"Screen Name"},{"type":"number","label": "Followers Count"},{"type":"number","label":"Following Count"},{"type":"datetime","label":"Date"},{"type":"string","role":"style","p": {"html": true}}],[1,"john",215,263,"Date(2016,1,10,17,07,38)",null],[1,"smith",315,363,"Date(2016,1,10,18,07,38)",null]]';

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jQuery.parseJSON(jsonData));


  // Create a dashboard.
  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  // Create a range slider, passing some options
  var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
    'containerId': 'filter_div',
    'options': {
      'width': "100%",
      'filterColumnLabel': 'row',
      'minValue': 1,
      'maxValue': 1000
    },
      // Explicitly positions the thumbs at position 3 and 8,
    // out of the possible range of 1 to 10.
    'state': {'lowValue': 1, 'highValue': 1000}
  });

   // Create a scatter chart, passing some options
  var scatterChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ScatterChart',
    'containerId': 'scatter_chart_div',
    'options': {
      'width': "100%",
      'height': 390,
      'legend': 'none',
      'pointSize': 10,
      explorer : {
            actions : [ 'dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset' ],
        },
    },

    // The scatter chart will use the following columns
    // out of all the available ones.
    'view': {'columns': [2, 4, 5]}
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(scatterChart, 'select', tableSelectHandler);

  // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
  // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
  // given the chosen slider range.
  dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, scatterChart);

  function tableSelectHandler() {
    var selection = scatterChart.getChart().getSelection();
    if(selection.length) {
      togglePoint(selection[0].row);
    }
  }

  // Draw the dashboard.
  dashboard.draw(data);

  $('.name-container').click(function(e){
      var selection = data.getFilteredRows([
        {
          column: 1,
          value: $(this).text()
        }
      ]);

      if(selection.length) {
        togglePoint(selection[0]);
      }
  });

  function togglePoint(index) {
    var color;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      color = (index === i) ? 'fill-color: red;' : null;
      data.setValue(i, data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, color);
      scatterChart.draw();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter_div"></div>
<div id="scatter_chart_div"></div>
<ul>
  <li class="name-container">john</li>
  <li class="name-container">smith</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its working, but one thing more after clicking on dot when user click on other dot or click on other list element like smith so previous selected dot's color should back to blue and current selected dot should be red.

Comment: toggle solution is working but it takes lot of time to set null all other rows and there is hundreds of dots on plot. So i have used following solution. Store selection in global var and then use this in name-container.click function **if (prevSelection) {data.setValue(prevSelection[0], data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1, 'fill-color: null;'); }** and in if(selection.length) use **prevSelection = selection;**

Comment: I am facing a problem, First time chart load 10 records and click on li work fine. Then by clicking on "Load more" button another 10 records lists in chart. Now there are 20 records in it. But when I click on newly added li that represent e.g 12 so it gives me following error **Uncaught Error: Invalid row index 12. Should be in the range [0-9].** can you figure it out?

Comment: possibly, do you have a new question, fiddle, or something?

Comment: No it is not a new question it is the part of current question. After loading another 10 records then this error occur

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7n07ybj6/4/ is jsfiddle. I unable to load with ajax. but after load next 10 results and then click on li it appears above error. This is the site where I am implementing it sandbox.ids.knowledgearc.org