# Change fill color of selected point in Google Charts API scatter plot

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Google Charts scatter plot with various points specified on it. I also have a side bar with a list of values corresponding to the points on the scatter graph and when I select a side bar value, it highlights the corresponding point in the graph.

I would like to change the fill-color of the selected item when it is selected. Currently, my working selection code is:

```
$("#select").on('click', function() {
    scatterChart.setSelection([{row: 1, column: 1}]);
});
```

I have tried using setValue() and setProperty on the data and have redrawn the chart but it has no affect.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35324649/5090771) should get you close, let me know...